# How to save generated bulk QR Code in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, qr-code

Im using the [qr_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_flutter) library and I wonder how to save bulk generated QR code into zip file. I had found one [tutorial](https://medium.com/codex/exporting-qr-codes-in-flutter-dd30220fcba4) about how to save generated qr code but it is not in bulk.

This button will generate the bulk of qr code using for loop after that save it to the gallery and the problem is how to dump all the qr inside a zip file or any method to gather them so that it is easier to share

```
CupertinoButton.filled(
   child: Text('Get QR Code'),
   onPressed: () async {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            String path = await createQrPic('ID1B$i');
            final success = await GallerySaver.saveImage(path);

            print('QR $i is $success');
        }
   },
)
```

This is the code for `createQRPic()`

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:qr_flutter/qr_flutter.dart';

Future<String> createQrPic(String qrData) async {
  final qrValidationResult = QrValidator.validate(
    data: qrData,
    version: QrVersions.auto,
    errorCorrectionLevel: QrErrorCorrectLevel.L,
  );

  (qrValidationResult.status == QrValidationStatus.valid) ? print('QR is valid') : print(qrValidationResult.error);

  final qrCode = qrValidationResult.qrCode;

  final painter = QrPainter.withQr(
    qr: qrCode!,
    color: const Color(0xFF000080),
    gapless: true,
    embeddedImageStyle: null,
    embeddedImage: null,
  );

  Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  String tempPath = tempDir.path;
  String fileName= 'jm-$qrData';
  String path = '$tempPath/$fileName.png';

  final picData = await painter.toImageData(
    480,
    format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png,
  );
  await writeToFile(picData!, path);

  return path;
}

Future<void> writeToFile(ByteData data, String path) async {
  final buffer = data.buffer;
  await File(path).writeAsBytes(buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes));
}
```

Comment: "Bulk" is just another word for "write a loop". What is it you have problems with it? Can you generate a QR code? Can you save it to file? Can you create a zip file that contains that file? Can you write a loop around those commands? *What exactly* are you having problems with? Post your code and tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: I've updated the question. looking forward for your help 

Comment: I should enhance my searching skill. Thank you for your help